Access denied when sending mail from powershell using SMTP
I'm trying to send a mail from a powershell script. The SMTP server I'm trying to use mail.xyz.com, some other person is already using it to send mail in a sql procedure, from the same system I am working on. So we know it works.
But when I try to do it from my powershell script I get an error saying
Exception calling "Send" with 1 argument(s) - "Mailbox unavailable: The server response was 5.7.1"
<abc@xyz.com>..."Access denied"

My code is
function Send-mail([string]$email){
    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "abc@xyz.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "subject text here...";
    $message.Body = "body text here...";
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.xyz.com", "25");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
    $smtp.Send($message);
 }
Send-mail  -email "zzz@xyz.com";

I am not sure why this is happening, I went through the old sql-procedure code where this is working, and it looked like they were using UTL_SMTP and then switched to UTL_MAIL, but nowhere did I see them using any kind of authentication. A stack thread said that authentication may not be necessary when sending mail within the same domain. Your help will be appreciated very much. Thanks.
